# Heroku Postgres + Spring Boot config org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet is closed

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I would like to connect Heroku Postgres with Spring Boot App.

Properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-75-251-84.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/ddjbpu7qcel282?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
    username: my_username
    password: my_password
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Exception during application start:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2839) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
```

What should i do to get my database connection working?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## PostGres DB Properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<host>:5432/<db_name>?ssl=true&sslmode=require&user=<username><password>&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

and following dependencies in POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Nothing else is required for connecting heroku postgres with your local application.